# Built in validate of title when using EntryModel?

Tags: plugin-development, saveentry

The example below will continue to save entries with the same title and slug.

Is there a built in validation when using `craft()->entries->saveEntry`?

```
$entry = new EntryModel();
$entry->sectionId = $sectionId;
$entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
            'title' => '123',
        ));
$re = craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into the `entries.beforeSaveEntry` event like this:

```
craft()->on('entries.beforeSaveEntry', function (Event $e) {

    // Get the entry we're saving, and it's title
    $entry = $e->params['entry'];
    $title = $entry->getContent()->title;

    // Look for existing entries with the same title
    $existingEntry = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry, [
      'title' => $title,
      'id' => $entry->id ? 'not '.$entry->id : null
    ])->first();

    // If an existing entry is found, prevent saving and pass an error message
    if ($existingEntry) {
      $entry->addErrors([
        'title' => Craft::t("An entry titled $title already exists"),
      ]);
      $e->performAction = false;
    }
});
```